# Add user with shell unexpected require_once

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add user with shell command I am getting this error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE) in /var/www/magento/shell/create_user.php on line 4
```

This is the file in shell folder

```
                                 shell/create_user.php                                               
<?php

// Create New admin User programmatically.
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
        ->setData(array(
            'username'  => 'username',
            'firstname' => 'firstname',
            'lastname'  => 'lastname',
            'email'     => 'mail@mail.com',
            'password'  => 'password!!',
            'is_active' => 1
        ))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

//Assign Role Id
try {
    $user->setRoleIds(array(1)) //Administrator role id is 1 ,Here you can assign other roles ids
        ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
        ->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo "User created successfully";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a question of formatting , It is working now

Just for information I use PHPStorm this is the code

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
        ->setData(array(
            'username' => 'username',
            'firstname' => 'firstname',
            'lastname' => 'lastname',
            'email' => 'mail@mail.com',
            'password' => 'password123',
            'is_active' => 1
        ))->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

try {
    $user->setRoleIds(array(1))
        ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
        ->saveRelations();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo "User created successfully";
```